# How to get in-app call information

Tags: iphone, ios, call

How can you get information about the call(e.g. caller's and calling numbers(or source and destination phone numbers),call date and call duration etc.),  which you make from your app using `openURL` method in iOS sdk? Any possible way? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590) is the best you're going to get.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle I Didn't understand. Can I get my required information through any way or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call log is not accessible via apple documented apis but if you do sm google, you'll find that  there are ways to access this info (iOS dependent - means iOS4 's method/api is different than iOS 3) using which you can access this log but then you won't be able to post the app on applestore.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, you cannot access any other App's data from your App

Comment: It means I can only make a call but can't get any relevant meta information about it?

Comment: @MuhammadQasim It's a user privacy thing.